# Dapper - How to return custom colum value

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have a class named "order"

```
public class order{
 public string INTERNET_PRICE{get;set;}
 public string SUGGEST_PRICE{get;set;}
}
```

Then I want using Dapper to  select a new column named "Total"

Total column's value is INTERNET_PRICE + SUGGEST_PRICE

If I cannot add new member to order class or create new class.

Is there have some way can do this?

```
    using(var connection=this.Connection){
    var sql=@"select INTERNET_PRICE,SUGGEST_PRICE,
                INTERNET_PRICE+SUGGEST_PRICE as Total
            from BS_GOODS_CHANGEPRICE";
    var result=connection.Query<order>(sql);
    result.Dump();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's stopping you adding a Total property to your order class ? You should also consider using numeric types for your numbers !

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as varchars in your db?  This is not a good idea

Comment: sorry,that is my write error. It is Int type in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with all the comments...

Below example is just to demo one of the many options using a dynamic object:

```
var result = _sqlConnection.Query<dynamic>("select a, b, total = a+ b from (select a = 10, b = 20) data").Single();
var total = result.total;
Assert.That(total, Is.EqualTo(30));
```

You can also look up mapping results to a Tuple.